# Client git repo hosting? (version control and deployment)

Tags: git, version-control, github, web-deployment

I've been using git and github for version control on my personal projects for a little while now. I would like to start using git for my client projects for both version control and deployment. The issue is I don't want to make it my business to host client git repos and it might be difficult to convince a client to pay the $7/mo fee for 5 private git repos when they only need one.

What are my options here?
I've considered hosting the git repo on the client's server, but generally they use shared hosting. I'm not sure it is possible to host a git repo on shared hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be, **for you**

**Free**:

- [BitBucket free plan](https://bitbucket.org/plans) (any amount of private Git repos with up to 5 members in team per repo), can say nothing about deployment part for BitBucket

**Not free higher-level**:

- Any [professional plan of Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/plans) (free plan doesn't allow private repos), maybe even minimal, if you'll use "naked" repositories, because one space allow any amount of (independent) repositories inside it, but you have to "share" other tools, if they are needed (and they **are needed** in work sooner or later)
- Maybe even [Assembla Portfolio](https://www.assembla.com/enterprise) will be acceptable ($10/user/month, but not for 5 useless repositories - for 1 full-featured space with a lot of useful tools)